# ReactJs how can i render the number of unread notification

Tags: javascript, reactjs, notifications

I am working on an application whose user must be notified if he has a new order, I have not found a solution to calculate the number of new notifications
[image]

every time a new command is sent it is rendered by orders.map()
I tested with this.state.orders.length
For example here I have 4 notification khouloud  has send 4 orders

```
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps, nextState) {
    if (this.state.ordersLength!= nextState.ordersLength) {
      //how can i do is this is true
    }
}
```

i don't found a solution
are there any suggestions

Comment: You need to add all of them together. Assuming that `this.state.orders` is an array, and that a single element of it is an object with a `newOrders` property, use `{this.state.orders.reduce((a, order) => a + order.newOrders, 0)}` to add them all together.

Comment: I think you will have to add an extra parameter for order object @ your back-end. When use clicks on a notification, set that parameter. While rendering orders, using that parameter on every order, you can differentiate between read notifications and unread notifications and thus outputting unread notification count.

Answer (score 0):

You can have something like this:

```
const notificationsNumber = notifications.filter(p => !p.seen).length;
```

So by this we assume that you have `seen` prop inside the `notifications` array where you define whether you have seen it or no.

And we just filter by those that we haven't seen yet and get the count.

Comment: (5,2,2) it's the quantity order I want to calculate the number of notifications received for example here I have 4 notification khouloud has send 4 orders i don't found a solution to do that

Answer (score 0):

Does your backend maintaining some status of notification after you check your notifications??? Your backend needs to maintain some key like readStatus of the individual notification ,so that you can filter them based on status.

`let unreadNotifications=this.state.orders.filter(each=>!each.readStatus)`

if there is no key present you can't do it.